# Generic property 'enabled' does not exist on type 'Node'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

There is a type `Node`:

```
export type Node<T> = T extends ITreeNode ? T : never;

export interface ITreeNode extends TreeNodeBase<ITreeNode> {
   enabled: boolean;
}
  
export abstract class Tree<Node> {
  nodeEnableToggle(node: Node): void {
    node.enabled = !node.enabled;
  }
}
```

Why I get this error message:

> Property 'enabled' does not exist on type 'Node'.

if `T` extends `ITreeNode`?

I also tried this:

```
type Node<T> = T & ITreeNode;

 initialize(source: Node): void {
    this.dataSource.data = source.children;
  }
```

The same error:

> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Node'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to recreate [a reproducible example](https://tsplay.dev/ymADQN) here.
As far as I understand, if you absolutely have to use conditional type, you may require to pass two parameters to the generic. Both being the implementation of `ITreeNode`. *There may be a better way to do this without repetition.*

However, I was wondering what extra goals are you achieving by having conditional type that you cannot do by using non fancy `extend` as I have done in `Tree1` class below?

[TS Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/ymADQN)

```ts
interface TreeNodeBase<T> {
  obj: T;
}

export interface ITreeNode extends TreeNodeBase<ITreeNode> {
  enabled: boolean;
}
export type Node<T> = T extends ITreeNode ? T : never;

interface TreeActions<T> {
  action: (t: T) => void;
}

// removed abstract to show examples below
export  class Tree<U, T extends Node<U>> implements TreeActions<Node<U>> {
  nodeEnableToggle(node: T): void {
    node.enabled = !node.enabled;
  }

  action() {}
}

// removed abstract to show examples below
export  class Tree1<T extends ITreeNode> implements TreeActions<T> {
  nodeEnableToggle(node: T): void {
    node.enabled = !node.enabled;
  }

  action() {}
}

// Examples
interface ATreeNode extends ITreeNode {
    extra: number;
}
new Tree<ATreeNode, ATreeNode>();
new Tree1<ATreeNode>();
```

Comment: I just want be insure that passed data has children property to build tree.

Comment: See `Tree1` class. It does that more simplistically.

Comment: Could you explann `U`?

Comment: Your type `Node` takes a generic. That generic it evaluates against the condition. You want `Tree` to take of type `Node` so you also need to provide what generic `Node` takes. That's why I added another generic, `U`.

Comment: Thank you, why I get error on line: `initialize(source: T): void {
    this.dataSource.data = source.children;
  }`

Comment: `public dataSource: MatTreeNestedDataSource<T>;`

Comment: These are new information. I cannot tell what is happening from these. I suggest you add a complete reproducible example, preferably, on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play if you want me to help.

Comment: I tried this: `public dataSource: MatTreeNestedDataSource<U, T extends Node<U>>;`